# How to Center CSS Tabs

Tags: html, css, tabs

been using some CSS tabs from CSS tricks. They work great, only problem is I need the tabs themselves to be in the center of the page, three in a row, like this site:

http://lewishowes.com/ (3 tabs right under the sponsors)

Here's a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/4zrsD/

And here's the code:

CSS

```
.tabs {
  position: relative;   
  min-height: 200px; /* This part sucks */
  clear: both;
  margin: 25px 0;
}
.tab {
  float: left;
}
.tab label {
  background: #eee; 
  padding: 10px; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  margin-left: -1px; 
  position: relative;
  left: 1px; 
}
.tab [type=radio] {
  display: none;   
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 28px;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label {
  background: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  z-index: 2;
}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="tabs">

   <div class="tab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked>
       <label for="tab-1">Tab One</label>

       <div class="content">
           stuff
       </div> 
    </div>

   <div class="tab">
        <input type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab-group-1">
       <label for="tab-2">Tab Two</label>

        <div class="content">
           stuff
       </div> 
   </div>

    <div class="tab">
        <input type="radio" id="tab-3" name="tab-group-1">
        <label for="tab-3">Tab Three</label>

       <div class="content">
           stuff
       </div> 
    </div>

   </div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.tab:nth-child(1) { margin-left: 30%; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4zrsD/1/

This won't obviously center it perfectly, but you can use media-queries to get it more centered depending on the screen width.

Comment: @ZachSaucier Well, it would require a lot of reworking with the html set-up to get it exact. And well, I'm not going to do all that work when the OP is showing us code that she didn't write herself in the first place.

Comment: He* ;)

Thanks for the answer, about the HTML reworking... can you point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: @user3299495 I really can't, since even reworking the html , might actually ruin the tab functionality. To do tabs in css it has to be set up pretty exact. I would recommend using jquery for something like this to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution that works for me:

```
<div class="centered">

   <ul ... >
      <li class="centered_tab" ...>
        <a ... >My First Tab</a>
      </li>
      <li class="centered_tab" ...>
        <a ... >My Second Tab</a>
      </li>
      <li class="centered_tab" ...>
        <a ... >My Third Tab</a>
      </li>
   </ul>

</div>
```

With the css:

```
.centered {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.centered_tab {
    float:none /*to make sure there is no active float*/
    display: inline-block
}
```

The `div` takes care of centering its children (the tabs). Make sure to remove any floating that would prevent the tabs from centering. `Display:inline-block` allow them to go nicely on the same line

Your example fiddle with my solution applied: http://jsfiddle.net/ufqduw6n/1/

Answer (score 0):

add this (may be help full)

.tab label{display:block;padding:3px;}/*reduce padding*/
.tab{width:33.33%;}/*same width for tabs*/

set another things according to content